# "Invalid type in JSON write (__NSTaggedDate)" when trying to decode JSON date

Tags: json, swift, postgresql, date, pg

I'm getting an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSTaggedDate)'" when I try to decode a JSON object from a databank that has a date variable. The error happens in the line: let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self) of the code below:

```
extension Array where Element == Dictionary<String,Any> {
    func decode<T>() throws -> [T] where T: Codable {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self)
        // 1.
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()

        // 2.
        return try decoder.decode([T].self, from: jsonData)
    }
}
```

I'm using this method to turn the result of a Postgres SELECT query into an array of Codable objects using the PG dependency.

```
case .success(let result):
   let array = result.rows.map { Dictionary($0) }

   let objects = try! array.decode() as [Model]

   completion(objects,nil)
```

Comment: You can't put a `(NS)Date` into JSON. It's not a valid struct. Only Array/Dict/String/Numbers/Null are allowed.

Comment: Why are you encoding data to JSON to immediately decode them?

Comment: I'm trying to turn the result of a Postgres SELECT query into an array of Codable objects.

Comment: That's not necessarily possible if the results are not themselves Encodable. Using JSONSerialization just elevates that problem into a runtime crash. What's the nature of `result`? What types are in the rows? Can you get anything more restricted than `[String : Any]`? I assume you don't mean "a mapping of strings to literally any type at all; a bluetooth device, a view controller, a UIApplication, an Int…"