# How to filter sensitive data server-side for object based on scenario

Tags: ios, parse-server

**Scenario:**

- Class `Example`, subclassed from `PFObject`. Some sensitive properties are optional/can be nil.
- User A creates examples locally on the client and saves it directly to the server (with ACL set to this user only)
- User B should only see a subset of this data.

**My approach:**

- create a cloud code function `getExample` for User B to call
- `getExample` queries those examples, deletes all sensitive properties on the results (or recreates the object with only allowed properties) and returns those filtered objects.

**Problem:**

- Whats the best approach to tell the parse engine that the return value is actually of type `Example` and make it parse it automatically? (call to server is via `PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: ...)`)?

Thank you (also, any architecture advise highly appreciated).

Comment: Could you clarify, what exactly is your question? Is it how to decode a server response to an `Example` class instance?

Comment: Yes. Especially how to decode the response with the least amount of boiler plate code. I know I could just create an instance of Example on the client and then fill it manually property by property with the JSON response but maybe there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth I found a good solution that ensures automated parsing of redacted PFObject subclasses. The trick is to add the properties `__type` and `className` to the return value so that the objective-c Parse SDK can recognize the type automatically

Cloud Code (simplified):

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getExamples", async (request) => {
    let query = new Parse.Query(ExampleClass);
    query.limit(50);
    let results = await query.find({useMasterKey:true});

    let returnResults = [];

    _.each(results, function(item) {
        // make a JSON copy
        let returnItem = item.toJSON();

        // delete sensitive properties based on internal rules
        if(thisSpecificUserShouldnotHaveAccess) {
          delete returnItem["maybeSensitive"];
        }

        // Mark as valid PFObject (important!)
        returnItem["__type"] = "Object";
        returnItem["className"] = "Example";

        returnResults.push(returnItem);
    });

    return returnResults;
});
```

Swift Class Code (simplified):

```
class Example: PFObject {
   public static func parseClassName() -> String { "Example" }
   
   @NSManaged public var title: String?
    
   @NSManaged public var maybeSensitive: String? // will be nil based on server logic    
}
```

Swift Retrieve Code (simplified):

```
    func callFunction<T: PFObject>(name: String, parameters: [String: Any]? = nil) async throws -> [T] {
        return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
            PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: name, withParameters: parameters) { (result, error) in
                do {
                    if let error = error {
                        throw error
                    }
                    if let parsed = result as? [T] {
                        continuation.resume(returning: parsed)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    if let parsed = result as? T {
                        continuation.resume(returning: [parsed])
                        return
                    }
                    throw Error.notAPFObject // defined somewhere else
                } catch {
                    continuation.resume(with: .failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Call to server:

```
let examples: [Example] = try await callFunction("getExamples")
```

Answer (score 0):

Decoding backend JSON responses in Swift is almost trivial nowadays, with the [`Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) protocol and the [`JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) class from the [Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation) library.

**Here's an example with an optional field:**

```swift
import Foundation

let jsonString1 = """
{
    "stringField" : "stringValue",
    "intField" : 1,
    "floatField" : 1.1
}
"""

let jsonString2 = """
{
    "stringField" : "stringValue",
    "intField" : 1,
    "floatField" : 1.1,
    "optionalField" : "optionalValue"
}
"""

struct Response: Decodable {
    let stringField: String
    let intField: Int
    let floatField: Double
    let optionalField: String?
}

let response1 = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonString1.data(using: .utf8)!)
// Response(stringField: "stringValue", intField: 1, floatField: 1.1, optionalField: nil)

let response2 = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonString2.data(using: .utf8)!)
// Response(stringField: "stringValue", intField: 1, floatField: 1.1, optionalField: Optional("optionalValue"))
```

**And one more example, with a nested object:**

```swift
import Foundation

let jsonString = """
{
    "stringField" : "stringValue",
    "nestedObject" :
        {
            "intValue" : 2
        }
}
"""

struct Response: Decodable {
    
    struct NestedType: Decodable {
        let intValue: Int
    }
    
    let stringField: String
    let nestedObject: NestedType
    
}

let response = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!)
// Response(stringField: "stringValue", nestedObject: __lldb_expr_10.Response.NestedType(intValue: 2))
```

**An example with a date:**

```swift
import Foundation

let jsonString = """
{
    "date" : "2021-02-04 09:38:33.000"
}
"""

struct Response: Decodable {
    let date: Date
}

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

let response = try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!)
// Response(date: 2021-02-04 09:38:33 +0000)
```

Find out more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

**UPDATE**

After discussion it became clear that the problem is that the object to parse is a dictionary containing objects that cannot be represented in JSON natively (e.g. `Data`/`NSData`). In this case it's possible to convert them into something representable (e.g. for dates it can be a formatted `String`). Here's an example involving `NSDate` and `JSONSerialization`:

```swift
import Foundation

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

let jsonDict1 = ["stringField" : "stringValue"]
let jsonData1 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict1)

let date = NSDate()
let jsonDict2: [String : Any] = ["stringField" : "stringValue",
                                 "optionalDate" : dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)]
let jsonData2 = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict2)

struct Response: Decodable {
  let stringField: String
  let optionalDate: Date?
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

let response1 = try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonData1)
// Response(stringField: "stringValue", optionalDate: nil)

let response2 = try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonData2)
// Response(stringField: "stringValue", optionalDate: Optional(2022-02-21 13:48:48 +0000))
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know about the Codable protocol, this is a very good and thorough explanation above. Unfortunately the response from the parse server has some objects (e.g. NSDate) that can't be decoded automatically with the Codable protocol ("Invalid type in JSON write (__NSTaggedDate)") so I was wondering if someone who is familiar with parse-server has a different approach.

Comment: @Markus I don't understand, JSON is just a string. And Codable supports dates, you only need to specify a date formatter (see my updated answer with a date example). It seems the error you pointed out happens when you use JSONSerialization (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56118373/invalid-type-in-json-write-nstaggeddate-when-trying-to-decode-json-date). Is it really necessary in your example? You can pass your response data directly to a JSONDecoder and have your pure Swift object as an outcome.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. The problem is that I use the Parse iOS library which returns a dict as result, not the raw json string. I can't really avoid JSONSerialization.

Comment: Oh, OK. Then you can convert non-compatible objects to JSON-compatible. I updated my answer with an example involving `NSDate` and `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: Thank you for the update. That approach still wouldn't work since the result dictionary already contains a `Date`, not a string representing a date. Maybe a approach is to recursively iterate through the dictionary and replace all dates with the string representation above.

Comment: That was exactly my point. If you have a type that doesn't do what you want you, as usual, have two options: (1) converting it to the type you want; (2) take over control of the source of data and return types you need. The former option means what you said, mapping the resulting dictionary. The latter option means migrating out from Alamofire or whatever you're using and using `URLSession` instead, which would give you more control.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. Wasn't the answer to the exact question I was looking for (see my posted solve) but might be really handy down the road for non-ParseSDK related parsing.